# Created WPF DLL but can not seem to get it to work within my WinForm when importing DLL

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, winforms, dll

Hey all I just finished compiling a DLL from a WPF that allows me to post "GROWL NOTIFICATIONS" on the users screen. The code can be found HERE.

The issue I am currently up against is the following (starting with my Winform Code):
Imports WPFGrowlNotification

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim themsg As GrowlNotifiactions

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        themsg.showNotifiaction("The title here", "notification", "This is the message here")
    End Sub
End Class
```

I've also added all references it needs in order for the DLL to work:

```
PresentationCore
PresentationFramework
System.Core
System.Xaml
WindowsBase
WPFGrowlNotifation
```

However doing all that, when i debug it and push the button, I get the following error on the line:

```
themsg.showNotifiaction("The title here", "notification", "This is the message here")
```

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   PresentationFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Provide value on
>   'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

And that's on line (on the Show()):

```
//Show window if there're notifications
 if (Notifications.Count > 0 && !IsActive)
   Show();
```

The GROWL code is this (just some of it - parts that are only needed here):

```
 namespace WPFGrowlNotification
 {
   public partial class GrowlNotifiactions
   {
    private const byte MAX_NOTIFICATIONS = 4;
    private int count;
    public Notifications Notifications = new Notifications();
    private readonly Notifications buffer = new Notifications();
    private const double topOffset = 20;
    private const double leftOffset = 380;

    private void MyWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //this.Top = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Top + topOffset;
        //this.Left = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Left + SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - leftOffset;
    }

    public void showNotifiaction(string strTitle, string strIcon, string strMessage) {
        AddNotification(new Notification { Title = strTitle, ImageUrl = "pack://application:,,,/Resources/" + strIcon + "-icon.png", Message = strMessage });
    }

    private GrowlNotifiactions()
    {
        this.Top = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Top + topOffset;
        this.Left = SystemParameters.WorkArea.Left + SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - leftOffset;
        InitializeComponent();
        NotificationsControl.DataContext = Notifications;
    }

    public void AddNotification(Notification notification)
    {
        try
        {
            notification.Id = count++;

            if (Notifications.Count + 1 > MAX_NOTIFICATIONS)
                buffer.Add(notification);
            else
                Notifications.Add(notification);

            //Show window if there're notifications
            if (Notifications.Count > 0 && !IsActive)
                Show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Any incite on how to go about fixing this would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use WPF in Windows Forms, you cannot just import the DLL and just use it as WPF and Windows Forms have many [differences](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/about-wpf/wpf-vs-winforms/).

You can use [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Class in Windows Forms to host a WPF control.

MSDN has a article on how to do this: [Walkthrough: Hosting a WPF Composite Control in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)